# Trouble Turning Computer On

Tags: power-supply

Basically - once my PC is 'ON' it stays on for hours or even days with no trouble.  When I shut it down (none of that hibernate stuff - 100% off)...it won't turn back on when I hit the 'power' button.

It seems like the way to fix this is to give the computer a good smack...after a few hits, the power button will once again turn on the PC.

I've had this problem for a while now and it seems to be getting worse.  I've replaced cases and the problem remains - so I'm fairly confident it's not a bad power-on button.

I want to fix this - but I don't know what is really going on.  My guess is that it is a bad power supply.  I've completely taken apart and reassembled my computer - it didn't help (so I don't think it is simply a loose cable somewhere).

Does this sound like a PS issue?  Is it possible my motherboard is at fault?  Is there any way for me to test these things without purchasing new hardware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like a discipline problem ... give it a *really* good smack.

No, no, more seriously, it may be a faulty connection (a *dry* solder joint?) caused by cooling from operating temperature to room temperature. What's the ambient temperatue there?

This kind of fault may be diagnosed if you apply a electronic 'freeze spray' to selected parts of the PC one at a time, while it's running, so the faulty component or connection is cooled and behaves as if the PC has been switched off for a while.

All the parts you mentioned would be potential candidates. Either take the PC to a repair person or try yourself with 'freeze spray' from an electronics DIY retailer.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know how hot your computer runs on average?  I've seen cases where someone wasn't careful when processing video on their laptop and ended up sustaining 200°F for a minute or two, causing erratic behavior from then on until it finally died 3 months later.

Comment: I don't know how hot it gets - but I can say that it's never shut itself down or had a BSOD.  This problem has been going on for 8-9 months now and my computer is very stable.  Once it turns on, it acts as my media server almost 24/7 and then works great when I play games like WoW on it.

The reason I'm trying to fix it now is that I'm getting a computer desk and reaching in and smacking the back of the PC is going to be awfully difficutl

Comment: " The reason I'm trying to fix it now is that I'm getting a computer desk and reaching in and smacking the back of the PC is going to be awfully difficult." This has to be the funniest comment I've read on this site.